# Heroku App is not working after changing aws-gem, works fine on local machine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, amazon-s3

I used to have `gem 'aws-sdk'` in my Gemfile, but updated this to `gem 'aws-sdk-s3'` to prevent unnecessary package loads. While this works fine on my local machine, the heroku app crashed with the following errors:

`cannot load such file -- aws-sdk (You may need to install the aws-sdk gem))`

When uploading my new app to Heroku, I do get the following warning, but the link on Heroku makes no sense to what actions to take:

```
remote:  !   Warning: You are running on a deprecated stack.
remote:  !   Please upgrade to the latest stack by following the instructions on:
remote:  !   https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/upgrading-to-the-latest-stack
```

Help is very much appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It worked locally because you have the `aws-sdk` gem installed. It doesn't on the server because it is missing from the Gemfile. Add this to your `Gemfile`:

```
gem "aws-sdk"
```

then run `bundle` and commit the changes in the `Gemfile` and `Gemfile.lock`

About the stack, upgrading is simple https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/upgrading-to-the-latest-stack#upgrading-an-app

Comment: did that work for you @bo-oz? If so, you can accept my answer.

Comment: Hi Thomas, it did work, but the consequence is that my app is now loading the entire aws-sdk suite of gems. I was using the "aws-sdk-s3" version, to prevent this. Any ideas if this can be achieved? It is being consumed by paperclip by the way. Happy to accept your answer after this.